# Android emulator 29.2.0.0 Segfault

Tags: android-emulator

Running Android Emulator on cloud VPS with nested virtualization support. 
 Everything worked find until the latest *sdkmanager --update*.  Now I am having SegFault on emulator startup:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export DISPLAY=:2.0
sudo -H -u vnc xhost +localhost
#sdkmanager --update
emulator @android-28-x86 -verbose -memory 2048 -gpu swiftshader_indirect -no-audio -no-snapshot -no-boot-anim -skin 768x1280 ${1}
```

```
Concatenated QEMU options:
 /root/android-sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64 -dns-server 127.0.0.53 -no-audio -serial null -device goldfish_pstore,addr=0xff018000,size=0x10000,file=/root/.android/avd/android-28-x86.avd/data/misc/pstore/pstore.bin -cpu android64 -enable-kvm -smp cores=2 -m 2048 -lcd-density 160 -object iothread,id=disk-iothread -nodefaults -kernel /root/android-sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis_playstore/x86//kernel-ranchu-64 -initrd /root/android-sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis_playstore/x86//ramdisk.img -drive if=none,index=0,id=system,file=/root/android-sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis_playstore/x86//system.img,read-only -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=system,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=1,id=cache,file=/root/.android/avd/android-28-x86.avd/cache.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=cache,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=2,id=userdata,file=/root/.android/avd/android-28-x86.avd/userdata-qemu.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=userdata,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=3,id=encrypt,file=/root/.android/avd/android-28-x86.avd/encryptionkey.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=encrypt,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=4,id=vendor,file=/root/android-sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis_playstore/x86//vendor.img,read-only -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=vendor,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -netdev user,id=mynet -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet -device virtio-rng-pci -show-cursor -L /root/android-sdk/emulator/lib/pc-bios -soundhw hda -vga none -append 'qemu=1 no_timer_check androidboot.hardware=ranchu androidboot.serialno=EMULATOR29X2X0X0 clocksource=pit no-kvmclock android.qemud=1 console=0 android.checkjni=1 android.bootanim=0 qemu.gles=1 qemu.settings.system.screen_off_timeout=2147483647 qemu.encrypt=1 qemu.opengles.version=131072 cma=272M@0-4G qemu.wifi=1 mac80211_hwsim.channels=2 androidboot.android_dt_dir=/sys/bus/platform/devices/ANDR0001:00/properties/android/ skip_initramfs rootwait ro init=/init loop.max_part=7 dm="1 vroot none ro 1,0 5159992 verity 1 PARTUUID=19E87A23-1C27-4616-8116-0088D1F64FD2 PARTUUID=19E87A23-1C27-4616-8116-0088D1F64FD2 4096 4096 644999 644999 sha1 3d4097abf29343cf6b86b9d6703c131e82429f69 5f81fddb8cc753b134fc2901766e57a49cfae566dba7ca48630fdddc30913f84 1 ignore_zero_blocks" androidboot.veritymode=enforcing androidboot.verifiedbootstate=orange root=/dev/dm-0 ramoops.mem_address=0xff018000 ramoops.mem_size=0x10000 memmap=0x10000$0xff018000 qemu.dalvik.vm.heapsize=512m' -android-hw /root/.android/avd/android-28-x86.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
 emulator: Android qemu version 29.2.0.0 (build_id 5871853) (CL:N/A)

 emulator: Starting QEMU main loop
 ./start-emulator.sh: line 5: 49651 Segmentation fault      emulator @android-28-x86 -verbose -memory 2048 -gpu swiftshader_indirect -no-audio -no-snapshot -no-boot-anim -skin 768x1280 ${1}
```

The machine was created like this:

```sh
sdkmanager 'system-images;android-28;google_apis_playstore;x86'
sdkmanager --licenses 
echo 'no' | avdmanager create avd --force --name android-28-x86 --abi google_apis_playstore/x86 --package 'system-images;android-28;google_apis_playstore;x86'
```

Any idea how to quick fix this? Any option to rollback to the previous version through sdkmanager?

**Edit:** tried Android 26.  Same thing.   Segfault.

**Edit2:** Also tried to install the emulator from here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+archive/refs/heads/master/sdk/emulator.tar.gz
I replaced the folder *android-sdk/emulator* with it.  Tried to run it, but encountered a *missing kernel-qemu* error.
Not sure what to do at this point.  The distros of *sdkmanager* and *android_tools* are incompatible?

```
                                                                        emulator: Concatenated backend parameters:
 /root/android-sdk/emulator/emulator64-x86 @android-28-x86 -verbose -memory 2048 -gpu swiftshader_indirect -no-audio -no-snapshot -no-boot-anim -skin 768x1280
 emulator: Android virtual device file at: /root/.android/avd/android-28-x86.ini
 emulator: virtual device content at /root/.android/avd/android-28-x86.avd
 emulator: virtual device config file: /root/.android/avd/android-28-x86.avd/config.ini
 emulator: using core hw config path: /root/.android/avd/android-28-x86.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
 emulator: Found AVD target API level: 28
 emulator: Read property file at /root/android-sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis_playstore/x86//build.prop
 emulator: No boot.prop property file found.
 emulator: Warning: config.ini contains invalid skin.path entry: (null)
 emulator: autoconfig: -skindir (null)
 emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file! Please ensure the file "kernel-qemu" is in the same location as your system image.
 emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is defined (/root/android-sdk) but cannot find kernel file in /root/android-sdk/system-images/ sub directories
 root@VS-683:~# ls -la android-sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis_playstore/x86/
 total 2816004
 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root       4096 Sep 18 17:06 .
 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root       4096 Sep 18 17:06 ..
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root        190 Sep 18 17:05 advancedFeatures.ini
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root       1806 Sep 18 17:05 build.prop
 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root       4096 Sep 18 17:05 data
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1048576 Sep 18 17:05 encryptionkey.img
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    6010832 Sep 18 17:05 kernel-ranchu-64
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1667536 Sep 18 17:05 NOTICE.txt
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root      18163 Sep 18 17:06 package.xml
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1701411 Sep 18 17:05 ramdisk.img
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root        297 Sep 18 17:05 source.properties
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2769289216 Sep 18 17:06 system.img
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1048576 Sep 18 17:06 userdata.img
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  102760448 Sep 18 17:06 vendor.img
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root       1235 Sep 18 17:06 VerifiedBootParams.textproto
```

Tried to create a symlink from kernel-ranchu-64 to kernel-qemu.  The emulator doesn't seem to be loading anything...

Hm... perhaps I should've download the emulator from the different source.  Not from the chromium project.

From here perhaps? https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-linux-4969155.zip

**Edit3:** gdb output:

```
Thread 1 "qemu-system-x86" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000898358 in ?? ()
```

Comment: There is an [ongoing discussion on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/d6gnrn/android_emulator_2920_crashes_on_fedora_wayland) with an emulator developer about this issue. A fix should be available soon.

Comment: @sfera, thnx for the info. I just wonder how the hell such things are happening.  Developers should have tests in order to detect in their software works correctly.  Especially if these developers are from Google. :))

Answer (score 0):

So I downloaded the latest emulator (5719087 - 29.1.4) from here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/android-emulator/+archive/7fa8974e268068384138470b4910f39f5c465236/linux-x86_64.tar.gz

I have absolutely no idea how I got 5871853.  It is not even available in the android repository.

So the conclusion is that one should never run **sdkmanager --update**.  This is simply too unstable.